# How do I add one column by numpy.concatenate?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to concatenate a column to the right of the matrix independent. The dimensions seems to fit but somehow it does not let me. Can somebody help? Thanks in advance

I added one dimension but the problem is still there

```
independent.shape
```

(100000, 4)

```
ones = np.ones(independent.shape[0]) 

ones = ones[:,None]

ones.shape
```

(100000, 1)

```
X = np.concatenate((independent,ones))
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 3):

They need to have same number of dimensions. use this to add another dimension to ones before concatenation:

```
ones = ones.reshape(-1,1)
```

Your original array ones is a 1-D array, while independent is a 2-D array. Also, in the above code, -1 implicitly finds the right shape for you. You just need to add second dimension to ones by that extra 1 in the shape.

An alternative to that is:

```
ones = ones[:,None]
```

Comment: Yea from my brief experience with Numpy to do some SVD stuff, when an array had dimensions like (n,), you would have to do this line of code to turn it into (n,1) otherwise it raises dimensions error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

independent = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000,4))
ones = np.ones((independent.shape[0],1)) # Column vector
X = np.concatenate((independent,ones),axis=1)
print(X.shape)
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
(100000, 5)
```